# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Henry' (AJAX & DRF)

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get a user's list with an AJAX request and DRF. But get this error:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Henry'.
```

I'd be grateful for any assistance.

AJAX:

```
const showUserLists = function(map){
  let userName = "Henry";

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/api/userlist/',
      data: {
        'username': userName
      },
      success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(item => { 
              console.log(item.list_name)
              $("#userLists").append("<li class=userlist data-name=\"" + item.list_name + "\">" + item.list_name + "</li>")
          })
        }
      });
};
```

urls.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter() #need help understanding router register
router.register('userlist', views.UserListViewSet, basename= 'userlist')
```

views.py

```
#this shows all lists for a user
class UserListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.GET.get('username', None)
        return UserList.objects.filter(user=name)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): #this is what we worked on on October 1
    class Meta:
        model = UserList
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'list_name']

class VenueListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = VenueList
        fields = ['id', 'title']
```

Relevant model:

```
class UserList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #is this okay?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Henry'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/anybody1/api/views.py", line 33, in get_queryset
    return UserList.objects.filter(user=name)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1380, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1319, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py", line 115, in get_prep_lookup
    self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/Coding/anybody/avenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1778, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Henry'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` is a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model, so if you filter on this, it expects the primary key of the `User`, not the *username*.

You can however filter on the username of the related `User` with:

```
class UserListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserListSerializer
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.request.GET.get('username', None)
        return UserList.objects.filter(user__username=name)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you, you've helped me out twice today. Regarding your note, is this particularly important? Am I creating vulnerabilities etc. by doing it the way I am doing it?

Comment: @vygrdev: no, it makes it more convenient if you later change the user model with a custom one.

Comment: Thanks, yes I plan to do that eventually. Appreciate the heads up. The feature is working as I planned now, thank you again for your help.